# Job is not current but still shown on Facebook profile

Tags: facebook, facebook-profile

On Facebook I have some job in my info. I have not specified dates when I was working there.

Despite that, though this job is not selected as "currently
working here" it is still shown on my profile page,
on the left side, under the About box.

Is this expected behaviour? Can I remove it from my profile page since I don't work
there anymore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can remove it.

1. Click on "Edit Profile"
2. Click on "Work and Education"
3. For each job listed either

   - Click the "privacy" menu to choose who can see the job (e.g., Public, Friends, Only Me, etc.)
   - Under "Options" choose "Edit" to make changes or just "Delete" if you want it gone

If you want it "gone" gone from your Facebook profile, then delete it. If you want no one else to see it, then select "Only Me" under the privacy options.

Comment: @AI E. If I delete it like this, it will be gone at all, I mean also from "work and education" section. I just want it to stay there as past job, but not show on my Profile page-is it clear? The only thing I see now, at least on my Profile page it says: "Worked" instead of "Works"

Comment: Then make it visible to "Only Me". Then no one else will see it.

Comment: @AI E. it seems that's the only option?